# Template argument deduction failure while passing address of const type

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, constants

```
template <typename T>
T go(T a, T *b){ T *t; return *t;}

int main() {
    const int x = 10;
    go(x, &x);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives compiler error:

> **error: no matching function for call to ‘go(const int&, const int*)’**

Why is the first argument a reference type `const int&` instead of just `const int`?

To fix this compilation error, I overrode the compiler deduction process by specifying the type of arguments `go<const int>(x, &x);`, but again why do I need to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a conflict of type deduction. `T` is deduced as `int` from the first argument, and as `const int` from the second argument. Hence type deduction fails (and the compiler presents a message which may or may not make the underlying cause clear).

If you want to make this function work without having to specify the template argument explicitly, you could make it so that only the second function argument drives the deduction:

```
template <class T>
struct NonDeduced { using type = T; }

template <class T>
T go(typename NonDeduced<T>::type a, T *b) { T *t; return *t; }
```

That way, `T` will only be deducible from the second argument, and the first parameter will use the deduced `T` without modification.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting, but do you think that would be a good programming practice considering the trick it performs internally.

Comment: @SauravSahu Once you start doing nontrivial things with templates, you'll find having such a `NonDeduced` somewhere is a must. And once you have it, you may as well use it. Whether it's a good idea in this particular case, or whether things could be done differently, depends largely on what `go` actually does in your real use case.

Answer (score 6):

Because `a` is declared to be passed by value, then in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call):

> c) otherwise, if A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for deduction:

That means, for `go(x, &x);`, for the 1st argument `x`, the template parameter `T` will be deduced as `int`, not `const int`. For the 2nd argument `T` will be deduced as `const int`, because `b` is declared to be passed by pointer (and the cv-qualifiers on the object being pointed are reserved; the same thing happens for pass-by-reference). Then deduction fails.

---

BTW: [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0MnavdiCTd7ljNiw) gives quite clear message for it:

> prog.cc:4:3: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting
>   types for parameter 'T' ('int' vs. 'const int')

Comment: I think OP reached the insight that the clang message gives. He asked why it happens

Comment: @sehe It seems OP focused on the *wrong* part of the error message; I want to tell OP that the error message about template deduction confliction would help more.